# How to upgrade to com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3 in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgrade Android Studio to the latest version shown here:-

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 16, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.20-release-275-AS7442.40), com.android.aas (3.6.0)
```

once the upgrade completed I have attempted to upgrade the `gradle` to `7.3.1`

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
```

which appeared to complete ok
however my application build now fails with this message

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.3/gradle-7.1.3.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.3/gradle-7.1.3.pom
Required by:
    project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File
```

My project gradle resembles this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.6.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

clicking on the link `Add google Maven repository and sync project` does nothing

how can I resolve this build error?

Comment: The AGP 7.1.3 artifact has been added now to the Google Maven repository just a couple of minutes ago (https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.android.tools.build#com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3), if you resync your project level build.gradle file in AS, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **maven url** from

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { 
            url 'https://jitpack.io' 
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

then press **Sync Project**

Answer (score -1):

I had same this problem in may macbook.
I was uninstall android studio and install again update patch 2021.1.1 Patch 3.
But I don't update gradle plugin 7.1.3.
I think 7.1.3 don't found in gradle website.

*https://gradle.org/releases/*

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

Comment: Gradle has nothing to do with the Android Gradle Plugin. The AGP is maintained and published by Google (see [maven.google.com](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=gradle#com.android.tools.build:gradle)). The linked website from you is the build tool only.